# Retrieving all records from Solr

Tags: solr

I am using the inbuilt Tika plugin to upload .doc and .pdfs to the index. I managed to upload some files. But some files did not have proper fields and are messing with retrieval.

I now want **to retrieve the whole index** for debugging purposes. I also want to see how my data is being stored, to gain a "feel" for it.

How can I fetch the entire index or atleast the entry for a given identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just quote the [Solr FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_get_ALL_the_matching_documents_back.3F_..._How_can_I_return_an_unlimited_number_of_rows.3F):

> This is impractical in most cases. People typically only want to do
>   this when they know they are dealing with an index whose size
>   guarantees the result sets will be always be small enough that they
>   can feasibly be transmitted in a manageable amount -- but if that's
>   the case just specify what you consider a "manageable amount" as your
>   rows param and get the best of both worlds (all the results when your
>   assumption is right, and a sanity cap on the result size if it turns
>   out your assumptions are wrong)

If you want to retrieve a single entry by identifier, then just query for `id:your_id` (replace 'id' with your actual identifier field and 'your_id' with the actual id value)

Comment: Is there any option to fetch all id's stored in the index?

Comment: @aitchnyu: fetching all documents or fetching all ids is the same scenario. Just as the Solr FAQ says: **it's impractical in most cases** . If you really know what you're doing, you can run a query for `*:*`, see the numFound value, then run the same query again with `rows=` numFound value. Again, I have to **really** discourage doing this.

Comment: Yes, thats it! Mine was just a test setup with 10 documents.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to see how your index looks like, I suggest using [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) (Lucene Index Toolbox). I used it once on a large Solr index and it was fine.

Comment: You could also use the luke endpoint / interface in solr's web interface.